# Favorite question star shows undo option even when I did not favorite it

Tags: bug, bookmarks

We have a star shown under the question votes which shows how many users have it as favorite as shown in figure.
[image]

But it shows the
[image] message even if I wasn't the one to "Favorite" it. It is a minor bug, but it may fool someone to Favorite it accidentally.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, the text "This is a favorite question (click again to undo)" is perhaps unambiguous.

But depending on how one happens to read it, it may take considerable effort to see what it means, and some users may be confused or even fooled into thinking it means the opposite--as you say.

So I think you're right. This would best be changed. Your suggestion of making it say "Click to make this a favorite question, click again to undo" would, I think, be an improvement. But I'd suggest this instead:

- For questions that are not favorited already, it should say:

  > Make favorite (click again to unfavorite)
- For questions that are already favorited, it should say:

  > Remove favorite (click again to re-favorite)

This has the disadvantage of introducing potentially unfamiliar words "unfavorite" and "refavorite," but those words have intuitive meanings.

This has the advantage of brevity and even greater clarity as to exactly what the effect will be of clicking the star button.

Comment: It's minor, but I'd fancy "Add this questions to your favorite questions" and "Remove this question from your favorite questions" more (with or without the "(click again to undo)" part which I find redundant (for example it's not there for downvotes / upvotes))

Answer (score 0):

All it says that to make the question a favorite, click the star.  Click again to remove from favorite.

I guess it's a little confusing, and maybe there should be a space in between, like This is a favorite question, (click again to undo).

Hope that explains it.

Comment: The `This is a favorite question` part is confusing. It could be `Click to make this a favorite question, click again to undo` or alike. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @RegisteredUser Just a tought, it does the same most of clickable entities do, i.e. just displaying what you should be thinking upon clicking rather than explaining what will happen afterwards